# Select Custom Post Types Per Category?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Trying to select custom posts by selected category

```
 $args = array('post_type' => 'speakers', 'posts_per_page' => 10,

                            //'category_name' => 'saturday',// <- solution A
//                            'tax_query' => array(
//                                array(
//                                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
//                                    'field'    => 'tag_ID',
//                                    'terms'    => array(2),
//                                ),
//                            ),//<- solution B
//                            'cat' => 2,//<- solution C

                            'tag__in' => array( 2 ) //<- solution D
//                            'tax_query' => array(
//                                array(
//                                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
//                                    'field' => 'tag_ID', //can be set to ID
//                                    'terms' => '2' //if field is ID you can reference by cat/term number
//                                )
//                            )//<- solution E
                        );
```

I just add 2 categories for post types but all custom posts are selected not only the posts with category id 2

All 5 solutions didn't work, I also flushed the permalinks by saving and resaving

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php 
       $args = array('post_type' => 'speakers', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 
                'tax_query' => array(
                  array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => 'saturday',
                  ),
                ),
              ); ?>
```

Try to change the custom taxonomy of the post type 'speakers'., as 'category' is the slug name of WP posts.